# html tag with runat=server inside MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Masterpage.cs doesn't recognize html tags with `runat=server`

For example in Masterpage:

```
 <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="ckb" />
```

gives the follwing error in code-behind when using `ckb`

> The name 'ckb' does not exist in the current context

**update** the input is inside `<HeaderTemplate>` of a repeater

How can I get to him and change his attribute?

Comment: Can you provide the line of code that is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using controls within a `Template` based control (such as a `<asp:Repeater>`) then you will not be able to get to the controls directly as you would with a control placed directly on your page / user control / master page.

Instead you need to use the `FindControl` on the template control itself.

For example, if you set an `ItemDataBind` event handler, you would be able to do as follows...

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
  {
    HtmlInputCheckBox chk = (HtmlInputCheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chk");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` you have given the control is `ckb`, not `checkAll`.

`ckb` will be recognized in the code behind.

Comment: That was my first thought (and comment before I deleted it)... but the OP does actually say "when using ckb" so I was willing to give them benefit of the doubt on that one

Comment: @freefaller - Possibly, but the error message certainly indicates otherwise.

Comment: I found the problem ,the input is inside a repeater header,how can I get to him and change his attribute?

Comment: @baaroz - `(HtmlInputCheckBox)e.FindControl("ckb")`